# Apollo useQuery is not making a network call when the input variable is same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a Higher Order Component and it accepts a prop variable input called "name". Inside HOC, I'm passing "name" as the input to useQuery.

If the name's value changes, useQuery hits the backend API and fetches new results but if the value remains the same, there is no network call made by useQuery. HOC gets re-rendered but no n/w call. I get the same response data as I got the first time (when 'name' was updated). I have tried the fetch policy 'no-cache' and 'network-only' also but no luck. Please help. I'm not able to find any solution online. Thanks!

Comment: show details? code?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Apollo caches that data. I believe you need to go to `no-cache` not 'no cache'. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/

otherwise, you're looking for refetch which you can call on demand

Comment: I tried the policy as 'no-cache' (sorry for the typo, I have updated the question). useQuery is not making a new network request until variable changes. Even if I stop the server, I see the data unchanged for the same input variable.

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma I think you should add your useQuery hook, your whole component if possible

Comment: I didn't understand, there should be a way to call useQuery (n/w call) even when the input variables are unchanged.

Comment: You're looking for refetch. `const { refetch } = useQuery(QUERY, {variables: {...}})`